# Why can't a Flutter application connect to the Internet when installing "app-release.apk"? But it works normally in debug mode

Tags: api, flutter, debugging, database-connection, release

In debug mode, everything looks good. I get answers and data lists from my API. But after creating *app-release.apk* and installing it on my phone, there isn't an Internet connection any more.

Here is my code:

```
ScopedModelDescendant<ReportPosViewModel>(
  builder: (context, child, model) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Invoice>>(
      future: model.invoices,
      builder: (_,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<Invoice>> snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(
                child:
                  const CircularProgressIndicator());
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // Something todo
              }
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return NoInternetConnection(
                  action: () async {
                    await model.setInvoice();
                    await getData();
                  },
                );
              }
          }
      },
    );
  },
),
```

Answer (score 272):

Open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file located at `<your_project>/android/app/src/main` and add the following line:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Add this -->
</manifest>
```

From [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest):

> Add the android.permission.INTERNET permission if your application code needs Internet access. The standard template does not include this tag but allows Internet access during development to enable communication between Flutter tools and a running app.

Comment: No changes necessary for iOS?

Comment: @SoonSantos yes no changes needed for iOS.

Comment: is this necessary for flutter too??it is flutter and not java project,I used this but does not work yet

Comment: @john This isn't like Flutter or Java, rather it's for Android. And for an Android project it is necessary to use it.

Comment: I think in debug mode we dont have to use this,but I add it to manifest but still does not work.I tested it last night and it was ok but now it does not work agian!!!

Comment: I have put permission in profile. Should i put it in main androidmanifest?

Comment: @RayCoder Profile won't do the work for release, you need to put it in a place mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Just inserting didn't work for me. Run/debug app required  before taking build

Comment: Important note: `uses-permission` comes directly under `manifest` but not inside `application`. Like `<manifest...><uses-permission... /><application ...</manifest>`. The official documentation about that can be found over here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking

Comment: @ImranZahoor It's already put directly under the `manifest` tag in the answer.

Comment: While doing this, it created confusion for me, so shared this, so others can took benefit from it. For me the example shared on flutter link was more clearer :)

Comment: I know it's not that relevant, but your closing tag says `maniFAST` instead of `manifest`. Gotta go FAST!

Comment: @MarwinLebensky Haha, thanks for pointing that out, I updated the post.

Answer (score 27):

If you had put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

And if it's not working, try checking the connectivity of the device. Mobile data or Wi-Fi on the Android device. Try using the Google Chrome browser for Google Search.

If it's not working, allow

> 8.8.8.8

in the DNS setting of the computer you are using.

Comment: I add to manifest internet permission but network not work, I also test in google and other  browser it work. just in application not work . but its work in debug and release mode when I get aab not work

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? @RahmanRezaee

Comment: <3 try checking the connectivity of the device

Comment: After adding the permission and stil doesnt work try reinstalling the app again, I did that and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

Add this to file *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml* after the package name:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add these in Android Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then run:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

Answer (score 1):

For my project, which uses Firebase, downloading the updated `google-services.json` from firebase console solved the issue.