# Flutter App doesn't connect to internet after realse

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

my flutter app is working fine in debugging mode but when I release it doesn't connect to the internet.

these are the app dependencies:

- cached_network_image: "^2.2.0"
- dio: "^3.0.9"
- permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.6
- flutter_local_notifications:  ^1.4.3
- flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

Comment: Can you share your main `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check if you have added the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[why flutter application can't connect to internet when install app-release.apk? but normal in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603979/why-flutter-application-cant-connect-to-internet-when-install-app-release-apk)