# Flutter IOS internet access

Tags: flutter

I have searched but couldn't find any information about IOS ,

On android to have access to the internet i have to add this key :

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

On IOS , the any confuguration need to be add to Info.plist ?

Thank you
Roque

Comment: You do not need to add anything to the info.plist

Comment: No configuration needed for iOS. Regarding to @CopsOnRoad on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603979/why-flutter-application-cant-connect-to-internet-when-install-app-release-apk

Answer (score 18):

Add the following in info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Doing this, resolved the issue for me