# Flutter iOS Emulator 'Failed Host Lookup' Error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, supabase, fluttermap

Hello fellow developers

I'm developing a location-sharing application with Flutter.
When I launch the iOS emulator, I encounter a 'Failed host lookup' error.
This issue is happening for both the map server and the backend server.
Strangely, some HTTP requests are successful.
I have been investigating for a day but cannot determine the cause. Please help me.

### What I've tried

- Adding Mac DNS configuration to 8.8.8.8
- Restarting the development machine and emulator
- Testing with both a fixed-line connection and a mobile data connection
- Running 'Flutter upgrade'
- Running 'Flutter doctor'

### Example Error Messages

```
flutter: ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'cyberjapandata.gsi.go.jp' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8), uri=https://cyberjapandata.gsi.go.jp/xyz/std/16/56527/26252.png?

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'xxx.supabase.co' (OS Error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, errno = 8), uri=https://xxx.supabase.co/rest/v1/yyy
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:119:7)
```

### Screenshot

[my app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQvZD.png)

Comment: Hello, "Failed host lookup" error usually caused by no internet connection. And if you sure the connection is available, add permission to use internet for iOS. Look for this answer to add the permission: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67607272/12566347

Answer (score 0):

Add in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
```