# In Debug mode working fine vs Build APK does not work, Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging, build

I build an App that shows an online image in the app as a photo view when I run the app in debug mode it's working and load's the image but I when build an app and install then does not load the images from the internet. I don't really understand what's going on. Does it need storage permission(**Note:** The image is not downloadable).

I build an App that shows an online image in the app as a photo view when I run the app in debug mode it's working and load's the image but I when build an app and install then does not load the images from the internet. I don't really understand what's going on. Does it need storage permission(**Note:** The image is not downloadable).[image: Build APK]

[image: Debug APK Working fine]

Comment: have you add the internet permissions in the Android manifest (AndroidManifest.xml )

Comment: I didn't add the permissions in the Android manifest. Can you guide me, how can I add it?

Comment: Thank you, for your guidance. The issue is solved now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why flutter application can't connect to internet when install app-release.apk? but normal in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603979/why-flutter-application-cant-connect-to-internet-when-install-app-release-apk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need internet access permission.
In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file located at `android/app/src/main` you need to add this permission inside the manifest tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml` and add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The top part of your `AndroidManifest.xml` should look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.yourappname">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[source flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking)

add: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` into AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you're try to load image from URL then make sure you have added Internet permission into your manifest file.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file located at `android/app/src/main` you need to add this permission inside the `manifest` tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest File in => `android/app/src/main`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
     **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>** 

<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="projectname"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    .
    .
    .
</application>
```