# Why is Flutter WebView not loading page?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am making a simple screen containing a WebView encapsulated inside a Scaffold. There is a button above the WebView. The WebView is not loading the page. However, when the WebView is not encapsulated inside the Scaffold, the page loads. I need to have the Scaffold as a container to add other widgets. How to make the WebView loads its page inside the Scaffold.

**Codes containing WebView inside Scaffold. WebView does not load**

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                 
                },
                child: Text('Print page'),
              ),
              WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
              )
          ],),),
    );
```

**Codes containing only WebView. WebView does not load**

```
   return MaterialApp(
      home: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
      ),
    );
```

Comment: if you are using the Flutter community Plugin of Webview. Then you need to use WebViewScaffold. Please check this medium link 

https://medium.com/@zeyadelosherey/the-complete-webview-in-flutter-d562b40c3260

Answer (score 8):

This code work for me. Try this out

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('test'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Text('Test'),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
   
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image: Cheack the screenshot]

Comment: this is the only solution worked for me. instead of `RaisedButton` use SizedBox() for better experience

Answer (score 5):

```
******Give Internet Permission in Android Manifest.xml file and the permission is below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603979/why-cant-a-flutter-application-connect-to-the-internet-when-installing-app-rel


<manifest xmlns:android="...">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifast>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2