# flutter build apk --release build the apk file but it give error after installing on Android

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-android, webview-flutter

I have converted  google website into Web app for android using `webview_flutter: ^1.0.7` package when I run the code in my physical device by making it external emulator the app work perfectly but when I build the APK using `flutter build apk --release` I got the the APK file and when I install the APK after opening the application it say `Web page not available` you can see the image below. I think it was not able to connect through internet
[image]

and when I install the app by making my device emulator it run perfectly you can see below

[image]

if you need more information regarding this please comment.

Comment: Can you show your manifest file and Your code too?

Comment: @RahulPandey you can see the important codes here https://codesandbox.io/s/flutter-ui-builder-forked-uql57f?file=/lib/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @RahulPandey if you need more code i can give you there

Comment: @MOHAMMADZEESHAN , I don't see Internet permission in your Manifest file, Can you please add the same and test. Reference link on how/where to add - [why-cant-a-flutter-application-connect-to-the-internet-when-installing-app-release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603979/why-cant-a-flutter-application-connect-to-the-internet-when-installing-app-rel)

Comment: @MOHAMMADZEESHAN Add Internet Permission In Your Manifest File and see if it works if not than we need to check your dart file

Comment: Thankyou @RahulPandey now my app is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml` Add internet permission

examble :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> // add this line

   <application
        android:label="test1"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Visit this page for more information [INTERNET PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)