# The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, version

C:/Users/khare/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.0/51736992f422993a1e741051bdf3c12801bc1ca1/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

What should I do ? How to fix it ?

Comment: ive tried the solutions but none of them worked for me, did you find the solution?

Comment: This scenario is fully explained in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74425347/114549

Answer (score 19):

In (dependencies) inside build.gradle (project), convert from `1.5.x` (x) in my case is (20).

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20"
```

to `1.7.10`

```
 classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"
```

It's highlighted in my screenshot:

[image: gradle version change]

Comment: If you are using compose then you will need to adjust compose versions as well.Normally with 1.7.10 of kotlin you will use 1.3.1 version of compose. Rest you can check using this link.

[link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler?gclid=Cj0KCQjwkOqZBhDNARIsAACsbfJ-gwm9EEG_S7fyNRC6QCv9RllloD3_TssX8mTi8YD2GdYfC3HagNoaAhKEEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds#kts)

Comment: Saved me after 2 hours trying to solve this. Thx!!!

Answer (score 9):

Just go to build.gradle(Project:yourProjectName)

**Change**

```
plugins {
  ...

  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.x' apply false

  ...
}
```

> [1.5.x means x version number at your case such as 1.5.1]

**To**

```
plugins { 
  ...

  id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false

  ...
}
```

It works at my case..

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the Kotlin version of your Gradle project.

Please upgrade your Kotlin library version.

For more detail, check the below link.

[Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that tired me for a week.
I had the below error:
**Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.5.1.**

I did all the necessary things, but the result was disappointing, including:
[Update Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699823/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o)
[downgrade Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603979/why-cant-a-flutter-application-connect-to-the-internet-when-installing-app-rel)
...
For me, the problem was solved by updating Gradle

Answer (score 1):

Inside build.gradle(project) convert from **$kotlin_version** :-

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`

to actual version mentioned in (ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10')

`classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10"`

Answer (score 0):

Change build.gradle (project)

```
 buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
         url 'https://jitpack.io'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when both of the below versions **were different**.

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.10' apply false
```

After making them both to **1.7.10** it worked.

Also don't forget to clear the caches and restart Android SAtudio

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin：

The binary (The Module) version of its metadata is 1.7.1 (Kotlin laguage version) , while expected version is 1.5.1 (as the compiler is 1.5.1).

This suggests that **the module's language version is set to 1.7.1, whereas the Kotlin Compiler version being used is 1.5.1.**

If the entire project is set to version 1.7.1, this discrepancy might be due to an incorrect recognition of the compiler version in a submodule. This can potentially be an IDE issue when transitioning to newer versions. When compiling submodules individually, they might default to using the main Kotlin language version as the corresponding compiler version.

Possible solutions:

1. Override the `kotlin.version` in the submodule to set it to a version higher than 1.5, preferably between 1.6 and 1.8, based on my experience.
2. Configure the compiler to use a specific compiler version.

maven example:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Kotlin compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version> <!-- Desired Kotlin version -->

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget> <!-- Target JVM version -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Other plugins as needed... -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Hope this helps!