# StreamBuilder not returning CircularProgressIndicator when waiting for Firebase connection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, asynchronous

I have a `StreamBuilder` that isn't displaying a `CircularProgressIndicator` when waiting for the results from the Firebase connection. I just end up receiving a generic `Null check operator used on a null value` error because of the dirty state. The error disappears once the connection is established and the `snapshot` is returned.

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
          builder: (context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Why doesn't it render the CircularProgressIndicator if `Connection.State == waiting`?

As replied in comments below. I am receiving the error:

`Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.`

Running on Android Emulator and the connection is stable/fast so not sure why it's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore snapshots, when loading new ones, are so quick you almost never will see the `CircularProgressIndicator`.

Furthermore, you're using a `else` clause that includes any other case. What happens is that when the code reaches this line:

> `itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,`

`data` is `null` and therefore you've got yourself a `null check error`.

Try the following:

```dart
final a = StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
          snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
        ),
      );
    }

    // TODO properly handle error cases
    print(snapshot.stackTrace);
    print(snapshot.error);
    return const Text('Something went wrong');
  },
);
```

When you'll try this there's a good chance you'll see `Something went wrong`: you need to investigate why your snapshots haven't got data.

Comment: Sorry, the `else` clause was added afterwards while testing. Code has been edited to show results. Now receiving: `Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds. This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.`

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, indeed you need to investigate the error underneath. In your case, there's an internet connection problem. Furthermore, in your edited code you still aren't checking `snapshot.hasData`. This *will* lead to errors.

Comment: I used your code but received the same error. Constantly, every 10 seconds : `[WatchStream]: (f9eedfa) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.` So definitely a connection error. It probably has to do with the emulator's connection. Thanks for the error handling correction.

Comment: If you're using an Android emulator there's a good chance you need to give internet permissions. Considering accepting and upvoting my answer if it's useful.

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606098/15831316

Comment: Same issue but most probably an emulator issue. Will test on a device later, hopefully solves the problem. Thanks again

Comment: DON'T DO THIS: `stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots()`.  Never create your stream as the stream parameter to a StreamBuilder.  For details, look at the first two paragraphs of FutureBuilder docs, or watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg

Comment: @RandalSchwartz yes, this must be taking into account, but I thought it was out of scope. @milie if you leave your `stream` like that you'll be charged for several reads every time this widget rebuilds. Use a `StatefulWidget` with a `initState` implementation to handle this.

Comment: I flag the "stream in stream" and "future in future" violations every time I see them now.  It's starting to be a bad meme.