# I got an error while trying to login into my app

Tags: node.js, flutter, error-handling, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to an app but during login, I am getting a XMLHttprequest error!

This is really frustrating and I do not know what to do..

I'll give you my code:

Login Screen:-

```
import 'package:docs_clone/repository/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:docs_clone/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void signInWithGoogle(WidgetRef ref, BuildContext context) async {
    final sMessenger = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
    final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    final errorModel =
        await ref.read(authRepositoryProvider).signInWithGoogle();
    if (errorModel.error == null) {
      ref.read(userProvider.notifier).update((state) => errorModel.data);
      navigator
          .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()));
    } else {
      sMessenger.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text(errorModel.error!),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 55, 55),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)))),
          onPressed: () => signInWithGoogle(ref, context),
          icon: Image.asset('assets/images/g-logo-2.png', height: 25),
          label: const Text(
            'Sign In with Google',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 17,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My user model:-

```
import 'dart:convert';

class UserModel {
  final String email;
  final String name;
  final String profilePic;
  final String uid;
  final String token;
  UserModel({
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
    required this.profilePic,
    required this.uid,
    required this.token,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'profilePic': profilePic,
      'uid': uid,
      'token': token,
    };
  }

  factory UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserModel(
      email: map['email'] ?? '',
      name: map['name'] ?? '',
      profilePic: map['profilePic'] ?? '',
      uid: map['_id'] ?? '',
      token: map['token'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory UserModel.fromJson(String source) =>
      UserModel.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  UserModel copyWith({
    String? email,
    String? name,
    String? profilePic,
    String? uid,
    String? token,
  }) {
    return UserModel(
      email: email ?? this.email,
      name: name ?? this.name,
      profilePic: profilePic ?? this.profilePic,
      uid: uid ?? this.uid,
      token: token ?? this.token,
    );
  }
}
```

My auth repository

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:docs_clone/models/error_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:docs_clone/constants.dart';
import 'package:docs_clone/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final authRepositoryProvider = Provider(
  (ref) => AuthRepository(
    googleSignIn: GoogleSignIn(),
    client: Client(),
  ),
);

final userProvider = StateProvider<UserModel?>((ref) => null);

class AuthRepository {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  final Client _client;
  AuthRepository({
    required GoogleSignIn googleSignIn,
    required Client client,
  })  : _googleSignIn = googleSignIn,
        _client = client;

  Future<ErrorModel> signInWithGoogle() async {
    ErrorModel error = ErrorModel(
        data: null,
        error:
            'I, sincerely apologise, because some kind of error has occoured in the program');
    try {
      final user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (user != null) {
        final userAcc = UserModel(
          email: user.email,
          name: user.displayName!,
          profilePic: user.photoUrl!,
          uid: '',
          token: '',
        );

        var res = await _client.post(Uri.parse('$host/api/signup'),
            body: userAcc.toJson(),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            });

        switch (res.statusCode) {
          case 200:
            final newUser = userAcc.copyWith(
              uid: jsonDecode(res.body)['_id'],
            );
            error = ErrorModel(data: newUser, error: null);
            break;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      error = ErrorModel(data: null, error: e.toString());
    }
    return error;
  }
}
```

Now my going to my server part..

my user.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  profilePic: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

My auth.js

```
const express = require("express");
const User = require("../models/user");

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.post("/api/signup", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, email, profilePic } = req.body;

    // Check if the email already exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      user = new User({
        email,
        profilePic,
        name,
      });
      user = await user.save();
    }

    res.json({ user });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({error: e.message})
  }
});

module.exports = authRouter;
```

My index.js:-

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");

const PORT = process.env.PORT | 3001;

const app = express();

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(authRouter);

const DB =
  "mongodb+srv://mumum:Lactogen1@cluster0.2oqm6el.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose
  .connect(DB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection succesful");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log("connected at port " + PORT);
});
```

I tried to login and expected to get to my home screen but got an error instead, Please give me a way to fix this. I have been trying for too many days.

Comment: If you are using Android add `android.permission.INTERNET` look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606098/5418940

Comment: Sounds like a normal CORS error. If your Flutter Web app isn't hosted from exactly the same place as your API (it won't be during development - and may never be) then you server needs to emit CORS headers.