# How do i make my real device in flutter establish a connection to my api service running in docker container

Tags: flutter, docker, dart, android-emulator

I'm kind of lost and i'm tired now. I need some help on how to connect my real device to communicate with an API server running on docker container in flutter.

I've been trying to test my API using real device in flutter. When using the emulator, everything works sharp but when it comes to using real device nothing works. I tried connecting my phone via USB and ran my flutter app but i got the error

```
Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 192.168.0.1, port = 2323, uri=http://192.168.0.1:2323/test-server/api/v1/auth.
```

This is my flutter server config class:

```
class ServerConfig {
  static const String _devServer = '192.168.0.1';
  static String baseUrl = "http://$_devServer:2323/test-server/api/v1";
}
```

i exposed port 2323 on the docker container.
I plugged in my real IP on my computer running docker but nothing seems to be working.
I've read a lot and i'm confused on whats the proper way of configuring the setup to work seamlessly.
Would love someone who can explain fluently...

Comment: add required internet permissions to androidManifest.xml https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606098/21590733

Comment: Have you tried accessing your API from a different computer on your network? Just to make sure it's accessible like you expect?

Comment: @VivekChib the androidManifest is as required...

Comment: @fravolt  i made my real device and computer connect to the same mobile hotspot (no internet) and now i'm getting Unhandled Exception: ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.0.1, port = 35568, uri=http://192.168.0.1:2323/test-server/api/v1/auth. :) any help...

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is: if you run your container on computer A, are you able to go to a web browser on some other computer B on the network, and access your page from there? If you can, the error is somewhere within Flutter. If you cannot, the issue is somewhere in your network or firewall setup. I also notice that in your error, you access port `2323`, but it seems to be connecting on port `35568` instead... that's the next thing I recommend you investigate. Is there some port forwarding rules going on?

Answer (score 0):

I read "phone" as "iPhone" in your post, so the following only applies if you are indeed using an Apple device.

### iOS

On iOS, your app needs explicit permission from the user to connect to devices on your local network. In my experience when you make the first request it immediately fails, and then shows you a prompt like the one here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/102229.

[image: Dialog as shown on the linked page]

Once accepted, "Local network" should also show up in the permissions screen of your app in the iPhone settings, as a permission you can grant/revoke.

You can also find all apps with this permission under Settings App --> Privacy and security --> Local network, and grant/revoke from there. Once again, apps that have never asked for this permission will not show up.

Perhaps you have rejected this permission once, and it hasn't prompted you after that? I don't believe you need to explicitly add this permission through your `Info.plist` file.

Comment: I'm using Android...

Comment: That's important to specify, and can make quite a big difference for issues like this. Be sure to include it in your question in the future :)